# Incorrect version of sed when compiling on OSX

Tags: macos, sed, compile

I am trying to install [`crosstool-ng`](http://crosstool-ng.org/) on OSX 10.6.8. At the configure stage, I run `./configure --prefix=/opt/cross`, and I get the following output:

```
! ./configure --prefix=/opt/cross
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /opt/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking whether sed understands -r -i -e... no
configure: error:
```

It appears that `sed` should accept `-r` as an argument, but doesn't. Looking up `sed` [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)  also suggests that `-r` is a valid argument, but when I run `man sed` I don't think my version allows for this:

```
SED(1)                    BSD General Commands Manual                   SED(1)

NAME
     sed -- stream editor

SYNOPSIS
     sed [-Ealn] command [file ...]
     sed [-Ealn] [-e command] [-f command_file] [-i extension] [file ...]
```

Does my system contain an incorrect version of `sed`? What can I do to make my `sed` compatible with `crosstool-ng`?

Answer (score 2):

`GNU sed` uses `-r` and OSX' `BSD sed` uses `-E` to enable extended regular expressions. GNU sed also understands `-E` which is an undocumented feature, but BSD sed does not understand `-r`. So you would either need to install GNU sed first and temporary change your search path so the configure sees it first, or perhaps you could try creating a wrapper around sed so the `-r` gets translated to `-E` . Then it still might not work, because the `-i` option works slightly different..